# Передать массив из PHP в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

У меня есть функция в обработчике, которая должна вернуть массив. А в Ajax мне нужно этот массив получить. Знаю, что нужно в Ajax тип писать json, но на странице никаких изменений. Поставил alert(response) и ничего не происходит.
Вывожу alert(response) в функции error в неё заходит. Что-то не так с возвращение json_encode

```
public function CheckProductInCart()
    {
        $message = array("", "");

        $this->checkSessionAndStart();
        if(!empty($_SESSION['product_id'])) {
            $message[0] = 'Yes';
            $message[1] = 'success';
        } else {
            $message[0] = 'No';
            $message[1] = 'error';
        }

        echo json_encode($message);
    }


function AjaxShowCart() {
$.ajax({
    url:  'http://practice/cart/CheckProductInCart',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
        ShowWindowCart(response[0], response[1]);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: Откройте консоль разработчика и смотрите там.

Comment: Открывал через console.log выводил
Ничего не приходит

Comment: При чем здесь console.log? В во вкладке сеть показывает конкретный вывод рнр скрипта. Вот его и смотрите.

Comment: Возвращает для каждого элемента udentified